# access header value from ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

We are currently using ng-grid to display click-able flags in a grid,
ie. cell 1 contain a green flag, cell 2 empty, cell 3 contains a red flag.

The flag represents the status.

To make the flag clickable, we have created a directive within each sell

```
<gridresultsummary data-ng-click="filterReportByOrderFromSummary()"  resultsummaryflag="{{row.entity[col.field]}}" />
```

the filterReportByOrderFromSummary() function at the moment, simply shows a static alert.
What we are struggling to achieve, it a way to pass the column header into this function.
we have tried many variations of

```
{{row.entity[col.field]}}
{{row.entity[col.header]}}
{{row.entity[col.headerValue]}}
```

however, still cant seem to capture it.

What is the syntax to retrieve the column header within a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
{{col.displayName}}
```

It will get you access to the displayName from within the column.

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/nuhazi/2/watch?js,output).

Comment: worked a treat! Brilliant!,  is there an easy way to get the value from the first column?

Comment: You can use a workaround. Don't think there's a clean way. Something like this http://jsbin.com/nuhazi/4/watch?js,output

Comment: apologies, i meant getting the actual cell value for the first column, not the header this time.

Comment: thats the one! thank you. is there a reason why row.entity[0] will not work? rather than hard coding the data type?

Comment: row.entity is not an array, just a document. Look at this example http://jsbin.com/huqekuhu/1/watch?js,output You can use workarounds, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116708/getting-first-json-property