# convert array to json object and call in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

```
$res = array:3 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "smval" => "xys"
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "smval" => "asss"

  ]
  2 => array:18 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "smval" => "deg"

  ]
]
```

Expect result :

> {first_id : 1, second_i d: 3, third_id : 4}

I want to convert this array to object. So I can call in ajax

> {first_id : 1, second_i d: 3, third_id : 4}

Comment: You started good but then ended not showing what you actually tried. Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can use json_decode() and json_encode() to encode/decode json string/ php array

Comment: look at below link Hope it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116708/getting-first-json-property

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` to convert Array to Json.

```
$res = [ 0 => [ "id" => 1, "smval" => "xys" ],
  1 => [ "id" => 3, "smval" => "asss" ],
  2 => [ "id" => 4 , "smval" => "deg" ]
];

$json = json_encode($res);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: I do not want all data just need id values in json format

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic properties to achieve that:

```
$ids = new \stdClass(); //Laravel way due to namespacing
//$ids = new stdClass(); //create a generic empty object
$count = 1;

foreach ($res as $key=>$val){
    $ids->{"id".($count++)} = $val["id"]; //assign the property to the object dynamically
}

echo(json_encode($ids));
```

Or if you need a specific set of names, you can use another array for the names:

```
$ids = new \stdClass(); //Laravel way due to namespacing
//$ids = new stdClass(); //create a generic empty object
$names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
$count = 0;

foreach ($res as $key=>$val){
    $ids->{$names[$count++]} = $val["id"]; //assign the property to the object dynamically based on the names array
}

echo(json_encode($ids));
```

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\stdClass' not found error i found

Comment: If you are using Laravel try `$ids = new \stdClass();`

Comment: s {&quot;id1&quot;:1,&quot;id2&quot;:3,&quot;id3&quot;:4}

Comment: You can use `dd($ids);` to see if you are getting the correct array. Then i would suggesting console logging the data you are receiving in the javascript side to see if it is what you expect

Comment: {#605 ▼
  +"id1": 1
  +"id2": 3
  +"id3": 4
}

Comment: Just rendering this to view it is passing as string i guess. var res = '{{$ids}}'; 
 
 console.log("s", res.'id1'); undefined

Comment: It is correct then. To have a json response in laravel you need `return response(json_encode($ids))` in your controller if you dont have it already. my `echo(json_encode($ids));` was just to demonstrate how you would get the response value