# JSON value parsing problem Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to access JSON key value, but it gives me nothing .

Here is the code :

```
                    let json_=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log(json_);
                    console.log(json_.tabs);
                    console.log(json_["tab"]);
                    console.log(json_['tab']);
```

Here is what I get :

[image: json parsing problem]

Here is a snap for detailed output :

[image: JSON detailed output]

Comment: Why stringify and immediately parse an object?

Comment: The object printed to the console has only one key and that is neither `tabs` or `tab`.

Comment: It has, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP2dY.png)... Whole string isn't showing here @Titus

Comment: @Pointy I'm new in Java-script, can you please enlighten me

Comment: If you've got a JavaScript object, there's usually no point in making it a JSON string and then immediately parsing it to convert it back to a JavaScript object. There are some circumstances in which that might make sense, but it's unusual.

Comment: the console is not showing any error, what will you have in the variable `result` can you please mention here

Comment: The screenshot shows your object has one key that starts with MUA-S&S so to access the contents you need `json['MUA-S&S 2019...........1']` - the dots here should be replaced with the actual name of the key of course.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried this `let json_=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      let i_json_=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_));
      let rr=i_json_['MUA-S&S 2019-07-13T14:44:32.711Z 1'];
      console.log(rr['id']);`   *But no luck*

Comment: Your value inside is a string (see the double quote marks), not an object. You should fix your code that generates the value. Start by removing all JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
let tabs_=JSON.parse(result[Object.keys(result)[0]])['tabs'];
```

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153369/10305444).

And here is [my project](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maifeeulasad/Chrome-SaveAndSleep/hijibiji/SaveAndSleep/background.js), if anyone is interested, feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The thing is you have variable `json_` whose value is an object when you do `console.log(json_);` the object gets print and the value of that object is:

`{ MUA-S&S 2019...........1 : "{"alwaysOnTop"............................................382}"}`

That is you have only one property inside the json object that is `MUA-S&S 2019...........1` and the value of this key is`"{"alwaysOnTop............................................382}"` which is a `string` when you are trying to do :

```
console.log(json_.tabs) // undefined
console.log(json_["tab"]); // undefined
console.log(json_['tab']); // undefined
```

the value you get is `undefined` as your object does not have any property with name `tabs,tab`