# How to extract and parse id from below mentioned response

Tags: testing, automation, environment-variables, postman, web-api-testing

Refer screenshot:

[image]

```
{
    "urn:pearson:work:876fa82c-9ad7-49c3-80c9-02d3b4c84312": {
        "id": "urn:pearson:work:876fa82c-9ad7-49c3-80c9-02d3b4c84312",
        "type": "element-authoredtext",
        "schema": "http://schemas.pearson.com/wip-authoring/element/1",
        "elementdata": {
```

---

**This is not working:**

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData.id);
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116708/getting-first-json-property

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData["urn:pearson:work:876fa82c-9ad7-49c3-80c9-02d3b4c84312"].id);
```

JsonData will have the full response , Id is inside "urn:pearson:work:876fa82c-9ad7-49c3-80c9-02d3b4c84312" field.

As it has special character you should call it as json[key] , then the next key which is id could be called as json.id, as it doesn't have any special characters

**Update**

```
for dynamic value use:

var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData[Object.keys(jsonData)[0]].id);
```

The above will select the first property , but if you want to make sure it is the right one then use array.find():

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let prop = Object.keys(jsonData)
prop = prop.find(element => element.includes("urn:pearson:work"))
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData[prop].id);
```

Comment: We cannot parse hardcoded value as this id is dynamic and gets changed everytime we hit the api

Comment: @SunnyGoel jsonData[Object.keys(jsonData)[0]].id use this updated the answer

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking the tick sign