# Jquery accessing index associative array

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
  var deptDictionary={
           <?php foreach($dept as $cd){
            echo '"'.$cd->department_id.'":"'.$cd->department_name.'",';
            }
           ?>
  };
```

which outputed this:

```
'Object {1: "ACCOUNTING", 5: "HUMAN RESOURCES", 6: "DEVELOPERS", 15: "ENGINEERING", 23: "ASDASD", 26: "QWEQWE"} '
```

now, I want to find the index of `ACCOUNTING` by just inputting the data it points to.

[what's that part called anyway if index is the first part of assoc array?]

I have tried this:

```
console.log(deptDictionary["accounting"]);
```

but it returned `undefined`. Am I missing something? Is there any reading material that points to js assoc array?

***EDIT:***
OK. I have reversed the key and the data, to fit my needs. now it looks like this:

```
  var deptDictionary={
           <?php foreach($dept as $cd){
            echo '"'.$cd->department_name.'":"'.$cd->department_id.'",';
            }
           ?>
  };
```

But I am still raising this question for future reference, if some other guy finds it important to find the key.

Comment: you have to go by key values: Try `deptDictionary["1"]` to get accounting.

Comment: you are returning a string instead of an object.. it is not a json formatted response it looks like you are returning a string value

Comment: no. the input I have is the word 'accounting' and I need to have its corresponding index value.

Comment: @agconti: you mean, I can't possibly get it through using the string and the only way is to use the key?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4491284/1754902

Comment: @FrancisXavierS.Antazo yeah bud Im afraid so, but you could do this http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/j5sX2/. (reverse the way you structure your object)

Comment: @UmairCheema Oh. sorry. so I delete this thread or just let it hang? I didn't notice that question/post.

Comment: @agconti: yeah. sad to say, It looks like I have to reverse the structure. thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/j5sX2/; (code below)

```
// this doesnt work
var dict = {1: "ACCOUNTING", 5: "HUMAN RESOURCES", 6: "DEVELOPERS"};
alert(dict[1]);
alert(dict["ACCOUNTING"]);

//but this will
var dict = {"ACCOUNTING": 1, "HUMAN RESOURCES":5};
alert(dict[1]);
alert(dict["ACCOUNTING"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that its case-sensitive.
If your output is like

```
'Object {1: "ACCOUNTING", 5: "HUMAN RESOURCES", 6: "DEVELOPERS", 15: "ENGINEERING", 23: "ASDASD", 26: "QWEQWE"} '
```

Then you should use

```
console.log(deptDictionary["ACCOUNTING"]);
```

Please verify what is your key?  `department_name` or    `department_id`        in `echo '"'.$cd->department_name.'":"'.$cd->department_id.'",';`

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you make an array and convert that in a JSON using `json_encode()` and to access that JSON object statically then you can call the way you were trying,

Ex.`deptDictionary["accounting"]`

OR

you can also access that using
`deptDictionary[Object.keys(deptDictionary)[0]]`

Thanks