# JSON get the first index name

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to detect first index name from my JSON object and this data come from API ..

if success data will return something like this :

```
var setRecharge = [{"data":{"transaction_id":"502014","tr_time":"2013-06-18 15:34:46","tr_channel":"WEB","opening_balance_a":"1000.00","closing_balance_a":"990.00"}}];
```

and if failed it will return :

```
var setRecharge = [{"error":{"code":"AccountA","message":"Problem with A account: Password is not correct"}}];
```

so from here i need to know the first index is `data` or `error` so i can continue wil if else statement ..

i try to refer this topic [Javascript: Getting the first index of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909003/javascript-getting-the-first-index-of-an-object#16874123) but not sure why it's not working and my data also has bracket and block.

Comment: Why not just check for the existence of `error`? Much cleaner than evaluating the physical position of it within the object...

Comment: You need to Parse JSON, then you can access the object as a standard array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: you should never rely on object properties key positioning as they are not guaranted at all in the ecma specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking the name of the element, you can check whether `error` is present:

```
if(setRecharge[0].hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    //you have an error - deal with it
}
else if(setRecharge[0].hasOwnProperty("data")) {
    //you have your data - deal with it
}
else {
    //something went wrong - you got neither
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just checking if the object has the `error` property, and then handling it. It's a much cleaner solution than checking the name of the first property. What if the order of the properties changes?

The following should work for your needs:

```
if(setRechargeRate[0].hasOwnProperty('error'))
{
    // Handle the error here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `hasOwnProperty` and discuss with me, It seems supported and has problems with old browsers but only DOM elements (do not inherit from object)

Answer (score 0):

Check the property directly

```
if(setRecharge[0].error!=null)//stuff for error
else //stuff for data
```

Comment: And what if you get this: `[{error: 0}]`? - you'll display _data_ in your alert, which is wrong.