# Get first key name from object angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have object like this i need to get "GetToolInfo" name:

```
{"GetToolInfo":{
            "Item":[
                {
                    "_Key":"DefaultPath",
                    "_Value":"C:\\Users\\vkedarix\\Desktop\\TAT\\Host\\DefaultWorkSpace.xml"
                },{
                    "_Key":"IsLicenseAgreed",   
                    "_Value":"1"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi... May i know why its down voted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Getting the first index of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909003/javascript-getting-the-first-index-of-an-object)

Comment: i am converting from XML to Object... so i know well i wont get duplicates...

Comment: take a look at the `Object.keys` method as well, it returns an array of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, This sample show to you how can get keys from object:

```js
        var app = angular.module("app", []);
        app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $filter) {

            var foo = {
                "GetToolInfo": {
                    "Item": [
                        {
                            "_Key": "DefaultPath",
                            "_Value": "C:\\Users\\vkedarix\\Desktop\\TAT\\Host\\DefaultWorkSpace.xml"
                        }, {
                            "_Key": "IsLicenseAgreed",
                            "_Value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            };

            for (var key in foo) {
                console.log(key);
              $scope.key = key
            }

        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    {{key}}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```